# Class java model of a object

Tags: java, object, model

I need to make a model of cellphone with:

- 3 types of dates with appropriate name and date.
- Set and get methods: at least 6.
- At least 1 method defining typical behavior of the object.

Can you please tell me how to begin doing that. It's one of my first projects and I don't really know how to begin with this.

Any tips would be helpful I just dont know what is asked of me exactly and how to go about doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do it. You need to create a Java Class to model a cellphone.

```
1.- A `class` is a definition of a kind of object, which models an element.
```

So you're going to make a class to represent this cellphone.

```
2.- Variables store data.
```

You're asked to store 3 different kind of data about the cellphone. Just pick 3, what about the brand i.e.? You can use it and two more.

You will have to declare one variable inside your class to store each one of these values. About the apropriate name, it means to don't call that vars "var1" nor like this, but something with semantic meaning like "cell_brand", which gives you the meaning of it when you read the code.

```
3.- Properties: get and set
```

Classes let us `encapsulate` data and methods inside it. Then, you need to make this data accesible from the outside. This is achieved by get/set methods. The first one let you obtain the data from the property you define, and the second one to change it.

```
4.- Methods
```

Explained simple, a method is "a piece of code which you can ask to execute when you want, without needing to write it again". It operates over the object where it's contained.

Then, you need to write a method to simulate one behavior of the cell phone: a call, a message, etc.

```
5.- Do it
```

You will need to look for how to make these things on java. There're **billions** of tutorials on Internet, I'll leave here the first I found. Good luck

[Java Classes](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm)